# String Concatenation not working

Tags: java, string, javafx

This is the first time that I am posting a question. Hope, I will remain active as coding is something I love. 
Just have started experimenting with Java.

Got this snippet of Code:

```
String  textData=new String();

        while (scanFile.hasNext()) {
            String text = scanFile.next();
            System.out.println(text);
            new StringBuilder().append(textData).append(text).toString();
            System.out.println(textData);
        }

        System.out.println(textData);
```

I am trying to read a text file and print it in another place. This is just a snippet of the larger program I am writing.
here, nothing gets concatenated into textData. However, text has data, which proves my text file  is being read.
What is wrong which I am doing here ?

Answer (score 2):

You append Strings to a `StringBuilder` instance and then do nothing with it. And nothing you do in your code can change the content of the empty `String` created by `String  textData=new String();` anyway, since `String` is an immutable class.

Change

```
new StringBuilder().append(textData).append(text).toString();
```

to

```
textData = new StringBuilder().append(textData).append(text).toString();
```

BTW, it might make more sense to cancel the `textData` variable, and have a `StringBuilder` variable instead. This way you won't have to create a new `StringBuilder` in each iteration of your loop. And At any time you can obtain the `String` representation of the current content of the `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

while (scanFile.hasNext()) {
    String text = scanFile.next();
    System.out.println(text);
    sb.append(text);
    System.out.println(sb);
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your StringBuilder out of the while loop and then append values to it within the loop. In your code, StringBuilder reset every time. Try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (scanFile.hasNext()) {
        String text = scanFile.next();
        System.out.println(text);
        sb.append(textData).append(text).toString();
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder textData = new StringBuilder();

    File file = new File("Sample.txt");
    Scanner fInput;
    try {
        fInput = new Scanner(file);
        while (fInput.hasNext()) {
            textData.append(fInput.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(textData);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Try this code, I created a sample file called Sample.txt with the following content:
Hi I am in college now,
Lets see if we can concatenate the content or not :-)

This seems to be working.

Thanks